# How would one access a distant public wifi network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I was wondering how I would access a wifi network around 2 blocks away. I looked into yagi antennas, but it seems like you need to have one on both ends (Which I wouldnt have because its a public wifi network)

The best idea I could come up with is a wifi repeater near/in the same building as the public wifi with a yagi antenna connected but that would require putting a device in the place.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Realistically you don’t and you have listed the one solution to your problems, but the problem of course, is the network is 2 blocks away and your not the network owner

Comment: I'm sure I've read about people using yagi antennas to reach unsecured regular omnidirectional APs from far away (back in 2000s); probably not 2 blocks away though.

Comment: @user1686 depending on the definition of 2 blocks this could be easily doable.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the laws of physics (Jim)

To get/improve the signal you need to increase the signal to noise ratio, and there are various ways to do this -

Move closer to the source (eg add an intermediate repeater as you proposed) or

Increase the signal / decrease the noise

- You can do this on the sending side by transmittibg more loudly or focussing the signal.
- You can do this on the receiving side by focussing on the signal source and rejecting noise and/or with more sensitive equipment.

For WIFI signals you need line of site + a bit (fresnel clearance) to get a good signal over a distance.  2.4 ghz typically goes further but has more noise to deal with.

You don't define 2 blocks, so no one can advise what will work. A yaggi could work, as could a parabolic antenna.  (Some people have used "Sky" Dishes and replaced the LNB with a wifi dongle to amplify and focus the signal, Cantennas - even pringles cans at a push - have been been used as wave guides, and it is possible to talk fairly long distances to even tiny  low powered "crappy" wifi tranceivers - so it likely is possible with a lot of effort and skill.  Maybe you can find and bribe a local ham radio expert to help with your quest - they are often a mine of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible. You will need a line-of-sight to the remote
antenna and a highly directional high-gain WiFi antenna at your end,
on the outside of your building. This will have a better chance of
working with another directional antenna on the other end
(although impossible in your case).

This setup has a cost, although you might be able to build your own
directional antenna. It might be simpler to pay for an internet plan.